# gtkmm: How to make stretched widget normal size?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the button and widget are stretched. How to make them normal size? Here is the main code.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "w.h"

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create ( argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.test" );

    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::Button btn;
    Gtk::Box box(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    W w;
    btn.set_label ( "test" );
    window.set_default_size ( 200, 200 );
    box.pack_start ( btn, false, false, 0 );
    box.pack_start ( w, false, false, 0 );
    window.add ( box );
    btn.show();
    box.show();
    w.show();

    return app->run ( window );
}
```

Comment: The result might look better 1. if you don't force the `window` to a specific size (drop the `window.set_default_size ( 200, 200 );`) and/or 2. insert something additional to consume the extra space of `box` (e.g. an empty label which you allow to expand). (I must admit that I switched from gtkmm to Qt a while ago but it might be worth a try...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I now use Gtk :: Fixed, and the size of the button is normal

Comment: You may want to read up on [GtkFixed](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFixed.html), because fixed position widgets are a real maintenance problem.